# Host Named Site Collections - HTTP to HTTPS redireciton on SharePoint 2010?

Tags: redirect, host-named

We have a Host Named Site Collection on our SharePoint 2010 farm and its URL is - https://test.demo.com. It is accessible with -  https://test.demo.com however accessing http://test.demo.com leads to "Unable to connect" error.

We want to place HTTP to HTTPS redirection, shall we make use of URL redirection?

Answer (score 0):

what is your AAM settings?
you need to update the AAM settings, adding another internal URL with http...which will redirect it to https.

```
Internal URL               Zone    Public URL for Zone
```

`http://test.demo.com       Default       https://test.demo.com`

```
https://test.demo.com      Default      https://test.demo.com
```